Compiler infers wrong type when using default value for discriminated union type
I have this (simplified) component:
export type BaseProps = {
    size?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
}

type ButtonAsButtonProps = Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'>, 'as'> & BaseProps & {
    as?: 'button';
}

type ButtonAsLinkProps = Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'a'>, 'as'> & BaseProps & {
    as: 'link';
    link: string;
}

type ButtonProps = ButtonAsButtonProps | ButtonAsLinkProps

const Button = ( props : ButtonProps ) => {
    
    props.as = props.as ?? 'button'

    if ( props.as === 'link' ) {
        return <Link { ... props } />
    }
    
    return <Box<'button'> as='button' { ... props } />
}

export default Button

These scenarios work as expected:
// TypeScript complains about link not being part of props (as expected)
<Button as='button' link='' disabled /> 

// TypeScript complains about 'disabled' not being part of props (as expected)
<Button as='link' link='' disabled /> 

The problem is when I do this:
// TypeScript complains about none of these props
<Button link='' href='' target='' onClick={} disabled /> 

In this case, I would expect TypeScript to use the ButtonAsButtonProps since 'button' is the default value for the 'as' prop and complain about link, href and target, but it doesn't; and it doesn't complain about onClick or disabled either, it's as if it's merging ButtonAsButtonProps as ButtonAsLinkProps. I've checked other similar questions and they seemed to resolve by not destructuring props, but I've tried that (as you can see from the component code) and it didn't fix my issue.

Discriminated unions need to be able to discriminate from the type some how, defaults are not part of the type, so are ignored.  Remember what's inside the body of your code is not typed (well not directly, inferred return types are etc), but type narrowing in code is only effective inside the body of the code and not exposed to type definition.  ps. In most IDE's, you can see what's exposed by hovering you mouse over the function.
But, you might find what your after using overloads, as each overload has a different signature, and that type information is exposed.  Even then you need something to allow Typescript to narrow the type, eg.  If we can make an assumption that onClick is only used for Buttons, then that will narrow the type.  If for some reason you wanted to allow onClick for links, you could always add onLinkClick event.
Simple example based on what I believe your after.
import * as React from "react"

function Button(p:{onClick: () => void}):any;
function Button(p:{link: string, onLinkClick?: () => void}):any;
function Button(p:{onClick?: () => void, link?: string, onLinkClick?: () => void}) {
    return null;
}

const a = <Button onClick={() => {}}/>
const b = <Button link="hello" onLinkClick={() => {}}/>
const c = <Button link="there"/>
//const d = <Button onClick={() => {}} link="bob"/>  error<- no overload

